# How to use jquery ui dateppicker i18n in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, datepicker

I am using angular 4 now and I want to add jquery-ui-i18n.min.js in datepicker but I dont know how to add in my component?

Here is my code :

```
onLangChange(langObj) {
        this.lanId = this.commonService.getCurrentLanguageCode()
        $( ".instartdate input, .inenddate input, .crstartdate input, .crenddate input" ).datepicker( "option", $.datepicker.regional[this.lanId]);

    })
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to use jquery in angular 4?

Comment: I use readymade theme @mast3rd3mon

Comment: then it doesnt seem to be very good as you shouldnt mix the 2